# Showing that ${d \over dz}\log\left[ z - a \over z - b \right] = {1 \over (z - a)} - {1 \over (z - b)}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that

$$
{d \over dz}\log\left[ z - a \over z - b \right] = {1 \over (z - a)} - {1 \over (z - b)}
$$

However my attempt yields that

$$
{d \over dz}\log\left[ z - a \over z - b \right] = \underbrace{\left( z-a \over z - b \right)' \cdot {d \over dz} \log(z)}_{\text{chain rule}} = \underbrace{{a-b \over (z-b)^2}}_{\text{quotient rule}} \cdot \underbrace{{1 \over z}}_{\text{log derivative}} \ne {1 \over (z - a)} - {1 \over (z - b)}
$$

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You applied the chain rule incorrectly. We have

$$\frac{d}{dz}\log f(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)}\cdot f'(z)$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice $$ \log(\frac{a}{b}) = \log a - \log b$$

Comment: Why is that? ${}{}$

Comment: @TestBang this is a simple property of logarithms. Have you never learned it?

Comment: No -- but I'm assuming one can derive it from the quotient rule and the chain rule.

Comment: @TestBang No, the property Lemur cited requires no calculus, only properties of logarithms that follow from the properties of exponentiation.